# How do I remove conflicting reference from git repository?

Tags: git, github

I currently have 2 symbolic references with master in the name as below

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:company/project.git master
9547e4ba01d67e1ff3xxxxxd5110eaaf2f48    refs/for/master
06106b7f1005dbb9f1xxxxxxxx456d2be84346c refs/heads/master
```

How do I remove or rename the refs/for/master so the ls-remote command only gives one result like so -

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:company/project.git master
06106b7f1005dbb9f1xxxxxxxx456d2be84346c refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1: Deleting the Reference

If you want to remove the `refs/for/master` reference, just delete it from the remote (using one of the following):

```
git push git@github.com:company/project.git :refs/for/master
git push git@github.com:company/project.git --delete for/master
```

## Option 2: Renaming the Reference

This is one way you can rename it, though it's significantly more work. First, you'll need to fetch the object that `refs/for/master` refers to. Only way I know how is to edit your repo's `.git/config` to fetch it.

For convenience, let's say that you add `git@github.com:company/project.git` as a remote called `origin` to your local repo:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:company/project.git
```

Then let's also say that you set up your `fetch` configuration in your local clone's `.git/config` file to be the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:company/project.git
    fetch = refs/for/*:refs/remotes/origin/for/*
```

Then once you `git fetch origin`, you can rename the reference to something else and push it again (you'll still need to delete the old reference though):

```
git push origin :refs/for/master origin/for/master:for/master
```

`:refs/for/master` deletes the old reference, and `origin/for/master:for/master` pushes the old copy of that reference as a new remote reference `for/master`.

You can read more about `fetch` refspec configuration for remote repos in [chapter 9.5 Git Internals - The Refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html) of the [***FREE*** online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: For `git push` documentation, see [git-push(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html).